# committing a bunch of files in svn

Tags: svn

In git you'd do this:

```
git add filename1.ext
git add filename2.ext
git commit -m "..."
```

In svn, in so far as I know, you have to do this:

```
svn ci -m "..." filename1.ext filename2.ext
```

ie. if you have 15 files you can have 16 commands with git. Which I think is preferable sometimes since you can spot errors more easily with shorter commands. With SVN is there no other option other than to do one big giant command?

Comment: double space would not make it skip files (why would it?). what OS / shell are you using? also: sorry, I don't understand what's wrong with running one long command. Many linux commands take multiple files from cli. If you want to run on many, you end up with a long one. I don't see the problem.

Comment: There were a number of problems with the initial command I typed, including the fact that some of the files were misspelled. I didn't get an error about the files not existing so I assumed the double spaces were to blame. Maybe they weren't. Ultimately, that's irrelevant. I successfully made the commit. What I'm more interested in is if there's a way to split the commit steps up. I've edited my question to remove the bit about spaces.

Comment: what shell are you using? auto-completion helps protecting against typos

Comment: I did do auto completion for most of the stuff. But if you have something like thisisalongfilename and thisisalongfilename2 then typing tab after you've typed in 99% of the string seems...  unnecessary. Just a matter of personal preference I suppose..

Answer (score 1):

You can run a command to extract the list of files, and feed it into `svn ci` using `xargs`.

E.g. if you want to commit all the newly-added files (with status="A"):

```
svn status | egrep "^A" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn ci -m "..."
```

I personally find it convenient to alias `awk '{print $2}'` as `c2`. The command can be made shorter:

```
svn st | egrep ^A | c2 | svn ci -m "..."
```